# PHP basename() removing variable, strange effect

Tags: php, opencart

I have a strange bug where in the following code where the basename() is complete removing the `$file`:

```
$files = glob(DIR_APPLICATION . 'controller/module/*.php');

if ($files) {

    foreach ($files as $file) {

        $extension = basename($file, '.php');
        print($file).'<br />';
```

When debuging, if I add the `print()` code above the `basename` it works as expected. If I add it below it completely removing the `$file`.

What could be the reason for this?

```
if ($files) {

    foreach ($files as $file) {

        echo $file . '<br />';
        var_dump($file);
        echo '<br />';
        $extension = basename($file, '.php');
        var_dump($file);
        echo '<br /><br />';
```

PHP Version 5.3.10

Comment: What `var_dump($file);` before and after `basename` shows?

Comment: @zerkms this shows that it is a string(63) before and nothing after

Comment: define "nothing" please. Also show **exact output** of 2 variables, as it was on your screen.

Comment: What do you mean "completely removing the `$file`"? Are you sure that there is a brace after the `foreach`? `as $file) {` <-- is this brace here 110% certain?

Comment: @Jon: if there was no closing curly brace - then the code wouldn't work at all. Currently it works (even though it does that in a strange way) ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: Sure, but that doesn't mean the *opening* braces are there in the original code, since we don't get to see the original code here. Maybe a pair of braces (half of which we see here) is missing entirely. And really, IMHO this is the most logical explanation.

Comment: What is exact string it is printing before basename?

Comment: Just updated the answer with full output

Comment: It works as expected, doesn't it?

Comment: @PLB No if you look at var_dump Output for: emailtemplate.php you can see that it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var_dump` gives different lengths for your strings than the number of human-readable characters it shows (specifically, each length is 6 greater than it should normally be).

This means that your pathnames contain multibyte characters, while the documentation for [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) says

> basename() is locale aware, so for it to see the correct basename with
>   multibyte character paths, the matching locale must be set using the
>   setlocale() function.

So, to solve the problem I suggest:

1. Use `bin2hex` or something similar to see the ordinals of all bytes that make up each path; this will tell you which character(s) in the pathnames are not single-byte. The 6 bytes difference means that it's *probably* going to be three characters, so my psychic powers tell me that the `www` might not be exactly what it looks like.
2. If possible, rename the offending directory to make the paths be single-byte strings and the problem will automatically be solved.
3. If the above is not possible, then:

   a. Find out what encoding the returned paths are in

   b. Write your own implementation of `basename` that uses multibyte string functions, passing them the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Seems fine to me:

```
<?php
$file = '/path/to/some/file.php';
var_dump($file);
var_dump(basename($file, '.php'));
var_dump($file);

string(22) "/path/to/some/file.php"
string(4) "file"
string(22) "/path/to/some/file.php"
```

http://codepad.org/E9Nb1SUG

Comment: Yes and this has worked for me in the past hundreds of times but not this time.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check by adding this single line on top of your code whether it is working or not..

```
echo basename('/home/shop/www/admin/controller/module/cloudbackup.php', '.php'); exit;
```